# Print model for craft object?

Tags: mesh

How do I unfold a model in a way that its print ready for paper crafting? Ive tried 123D Make for crafts and its not working out the way I want it too, also I dont have windows for Pepakura (?)

Comment: Hi Emily, welcome to GD:SE, your question is a little unclear. You want to unfold an already put together model to see the template for printing? Your question is also low quality to maybe off topic (we no longer accept questions that deal with 3D programs) for our site. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired result using the UV mapping feature.

Start with <kbd>U</kbd> to bring up the unwrap menu. There will be several options. Try smart UV project. After doing that, hit <kbd>F6</kbd>, and set the Island Margin to 0.03, so you can see the gaps. Next open up the UV image editor, and you should see the layout inside. This is how the paper template will look. If you don't like it (probably to many separate parts) you can use a manual process.

To manually define the cuts, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>  to enter edit mode. Select the edges where you will wan't gaps. Be sure to select enough that it can sit flat. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>>*Mark seems* then use <kbd>U</kbd>>*Unwrap* and set the Island margin to 0.03.

Finally, when you're satisfied with your layout, Go to *UVs*>*Export Uv Layout* and save the image.

Useful further reading and help:

- Importing an OBJ file: https://youtu.be/5t2Ntn6JDAY?t=1m53s